# The 32-bit version o fthe Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor cannot be used to debug 64-bit processes?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to run my visual studio (2010) C++ project on an old Windows XP machine that is running VS2010.  However, when I run it, I get the error listed in the title of this question.  Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The title already provides the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, a debugger should be the same bitness as the debuggee (or at least it must be able to understand the architecture of the target). In any common siutation, an x86-based debugger will not be able to debug an x64 application.

The [Visual Studio documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184681.aspx) says:

> To debug a 64-bit application that is running on a remote computer,
>   you need to install the 64-bit remote debugger on the remote computer.
>   The 64-bit remote debugger is available on the last disc of your
>   Visual Studio installation set.

Comment: But it's Visual Studio 2010... I run the same IDE on other machines without a problem?

Comment: Visual Studio has 32-bit and 64-bit components.  On a 64-bit machine, you can install the 64-bit debugging tools.  On a 32-bit machine, you can't.

Answer (score 7):

Same error was throwing for me when I had Silverlight debugger enabled. To resolve this issue

- Open project properties
- Under web tab look for Debuggers
- Remove the tick mark on "Silverlight"